# Error when including c and c++ libraries in Arduino

Tags: arduino

when I try to compile the .ino file I get an import error. This is the structure:

main file in ~/Documents/Arduino/inos/mpu9250test/mpu9250test.ino in which I add `#include "mpudmp.h"`

That file is in the path ~/Documents/Arduino/libraries/mpudmp/mpudmp.h and also contains the imports:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "helper_3dmath.h"
#include "mpudmp_registers.h"
```

What I understand is that sys/time.h and cmath are C and C++ libraries respectively. That first is located at /usr/include/sys/time.h and the second at /usr/include/sys/c++/4.2.1/cmath. Now when I compile I get the following error:

```
/Users/sebamenabar/Documents/Arduino/libraries/mpudmp/mpudmp.h:31:17: fatal error: cmath: No such file or directory #include <cmath>
```

And if I comment the line importing cmath in the mpudump.h I also have and error with the time.h:

```
/Users/sebamenabar/Documents/Arduino/libraries/mpudmp/mpudmp.h:32:22: fatal error: sys/time.h: No such file or directory #include <sys/time.h>
```

I'm running MacOS with GCC installed and my objective is to program an Arduino Pro Mini

Answer (score 0):

The problem with GCC is that it doesn't links in the std C++ libraries by default as G++ does. So it is always advisable to use G++ when compiling C++ files. The result can be same with both GCC and G++ if you do know the exact arguments to link them.